# Functions $f$ that satisfy $f(x) + f(1/x) = \rm constant$ for each $x$.

Tags: functional-equations, elementary-functions

Hello I am thinking about all the functions that satisfy 
$$
f(x)+f(1/x) = C
$$
for each $x$. The constant $C$ is the same for all $x$ in the Domain.

It is clear that $\log_a(x)$ works for all possible bases. Can you think of another function?

Comment: For all $x>0$, we have $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$$

Comment: If $f(x)$ is one such function, then $g(x)=af(x)+b$ is another.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is one such function, then so is $f(1/x)$.

Comment: @Adren, good example, though. If I make the correction $f(x) = arctan(\sqrt{x}) + arctan(1/\sqrt{x}) = \pi/2$ for all $x>0$ and this is everything in the domain now.

Comment: @Veliko Right; or you can consider $f(x)=sgn(x)\,\arctan(x)$ where $sgn$ denotes the sign function. Now you have :
$\forall x\neq0,\,f(x)+f(1/x)=\pi/2$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any function $h(x)$, let $f(x)=A[h(x)-h(1/x)]+B$. Then, 
$$
f(1/x)=A[h(1/x)-h(x)]+B\implies f(x)+f(1/x)=2B.
$$

Comment: So, for example, $x-\frac1x$ works?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, it does.

Comment: This is probably the most general answer possible for continuous functions. Caution is needed when working with the Domain. But thank you very much.